# Demonstrate the following ....

Tags: geometry

The diagonals of a trapezoid (ABCD where AD parallel to BC ) divide it into four triangles all having one vertice in O. Knowing that the area of triangle $\triangle AOD$ is $A_1$ and of $\triangle BOC$ is $A_2$, demonstrate that the area of the trapezoid is

$$(\sqrt{A_1} + \sqrt{A_2})^2$$

Thank you very much if you are now looking at my problem!

Comment: I like your sense of humour.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207343/sqrtaabcd-sqrtaabe-sqrtacde#comment1412179_207343

Comment: @Awesome Thanks!

Comment: Elementary, my dear John.

Comment: @Awesome This is exactly how I would have done it. +1

Comment: I wish your last name was Watson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ADC$ have the same area (same base, equal heights). They have $\triangle AOD$ in common, so the areas of the two parts where they differ are equal, That is, $\triangle AOB$ has the same area as $\triangle DOC$.

Call the area of each by the name $x$.

Look at $\triangle ABC$. It is divided into two parts, with bases $AO$ and $OC$, and the same heights. Thus
$$\frac{x}{A_2}=\frac{OA}{OC}.\tag{1}$$

A similar calculation using $\triangle ACD$ shows that
$$\frac{x}{A_1}=\frac{OC}{OA}.\tag{2}$$
Multiply the left sides of (1) and (2), and the right sides. We get
$$\frac{x^2}{A_1A_2}=1,$$
which tells us that $x=\sqrt{A_1A_2}$ and we are finished.

Comment: That is better than my lazy method.

Comment: I don't think so. In this sort of thing, there is virtue in showing that mechanical calculation is enough.

Comment: So here can we suppose that the trapezoid is an isoscele one?, because I see you wrote that triangles ABD and ADC have the same area.

Comment: @JohnG. They will have same area in any general trapezoid. make a diagram and see their base and height as Andre says

Comment: @Awesome I think your idea about Watson has a bit of truth in it:)

Comment: :)­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 2):

Let $AD= a$ (smaller side). $BC=b$. Height of trapezoid $=h$.

Then,
$ABC+BDC-A_2+A_1=ABD+ACD-A_1+A_2=\text{Area of trapezoid}$

Let height of $AOD$ = y , then height of $BOC=h-y$

$A_1=ay/2$.

$A_2=b(h-y)/2$

Find area of other triangles using $base*height/2$

Find y.

Find $(\sqrt{A_1}+\sqrt{A_2})^2$

Simplify to well known formula of area of trapezoid.