# Find the area of the trapezium

Tags: geometry

ABCD is trapezium AB||CD. 10 & 40 are the areas of the respective parts

[image]

How to find out the area of the trapezium?

Comment: Keep in mind that $\sqrt{\text{Area}}=\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{40}$ :)

Comment: @Sawarnik Interesting. Like to briefly explain how it can be proved?

Comment: @Sawarnik Found the proof from M Josefsson, but it is good to bring that up.

Comment: @Mick Glad you found it :) Its been on SE twice as well, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739672/demonstrate-the-following?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\triangle COD \sim \triangle AOB.$$

If $\dfrac{CD}{AB}=a$, then $\dfrac{\text{Area of}\space \triangle COD}{\text{Area of} \space \triangle AOB}=a^2$.

So, we conclude: $\dfrac{CD}{AB}=\sqrt{\frac{40}{10}}=\sqrt{4}=2$.

If we denote trapezium total height $h$, then 
heights of corresponding triangles are $\frac{2h}{3}$ and $\frac{h}{3}$ (all linear ratios of triangles $\triangle AOB$ and $\triangle COD$ are $\equiv 2$).

$\text{Area of} \space \triangle COD=\dfrac{CD}{2}\cdot \dfrac{2h}{3}=40$ $\implies$ $CD\cdot h=3\cdot 40=120$,

$\text{Area of} \space \triangle AOB=\dfrac{AB}{2} \cdot \dfrac{h}{3}=10$ $\implies$ $AB\cdot h = 6\cdot 10=60$;

Now Area of trapezium is

$$
\dfrac{AB+CD}{2}\cdot h = \frac{(120+60)}{2}=90.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the diagonals intersect at P.

As pointed out, $\dfrac {DC}{AB} = \dfrac {2}{1}.$

Geometric theorems:-

I. If 2 ⊿s have the same altitude, then the ratio of their areas is equal to the ratio of their bases.

[Corollary of I]

II. If 2 ⊿s have the same altitude,their areas are the same when they have equal bases.

[image]

By (II), area of ⊿PDA = area of ⊿PCB = x, say.

By (I), $\dfrac {40 + x}{10 + x} = \dfrac {2}{1}$

Then x = 20 and the result follows.