# finding the area of a trapezoid using only 2 of the 4 triangles that makes up its interior

Tags: geometry

Given a trapezoid $ABCD$ with its diagonals drawn and $E$ is the point where the diagonals intersect. Then the trapezoid is divided up into 4 triangles. Theres a well known theorem that if $k_{1},k_{2},k_{3},k_{4}$ are the areas of each of the four triangles then, $k_{1} \cdot k_{3} = k_{2} \cdot k_{4}$ Is it possible to find the area of the trapezoid if you only knew the area of two of the four triangles that make it up using the theorem above?

Comment: I have posted my answer (and have it deleted now) because there is one question I need to ask. Are the k’s the lengths (instead of areas) of the 4 segments formed by the intersection of the diagonals such $AE = k_1, EC = k_2, DE = k_3 and BE = k_4 $?

Comment: No the $k$'s are the areas of the four triangles. So for example triangle $ABE$ has area $k_{1}$. When the diagonals are drawn you get four triangles. Clearly if you summed up the area of the four triangles you would get the area of the trapezoid. What if you were only given the area of two of the four triangles call them $z$ and $Z$? Would it be possible to find an expression for the area of the trapezoid using only this information? And if it works how many different expressions can one get?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207343/sqrtaabcd-sqrtaabe-sqrtacde#comment1412179_207343

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the figure drawn according to the given.

[image]
 $k_1 … k_4$ has to be arranged as such according to (1) the given equality and (2) ratio of the areas is proportional to bases if the altitude is the same.

Also, by (2) again, $k_2 = k_4$ ….. (*)

If 2 of the areas of triangles are given, depending which two, we have to separate the study into the following cases. For simplicity, I will use {i} to represent $k_i$ for i = 1, … 4

Case-1 If {1} and {2} are known, then {4} is also known because of (*) and then {3} can be found from the given relation.

Case-2 If {1} and {4} are known, this same as case-1.

Case-3 If {2} and {4} are known, then $k_1 \cdot k_3 = (k_2)^2$. No further result can be developed.

Case-4 If {3} and {4} are known, similar to case-1.

Case-5 if {2} and {3} are known, similar to case-1.

Case-6 If {1} and {3} are known, then {2}= {4} $= \sqrt (k_1 \cdot k_3)$.